# Generate and validate session in node.js

Tags: authentication, session, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

What is a correct way to generate session and than validate it on every request?

Registration and initial authentication (user identity check for generating session) is handled by external service, so it's out of the question.

To simplify a question, what is the native secure way to generate and encrypt session with secret.

---

**Requirements (alternatives is welcomed)**:

- Session should be of two parts, one stored in cookies, second in database.
- User check handled by server using database session part, cookies part and validate function.
- Session generating and validating functions stored on server side and not accessible to user.
- If database session part or functions is compromised, hacker couldn't make request pretending to be user. For this he will need to steal user cookies or session generate function and database session part.
- Multiple device support with the same database session part.
- JWT is not usable as logout is needed on server side (database session part will be deleted and all devices wouldn't be able to login with old cookies session part). User had some trust level that can change and it's will require JWT invalidation, so sessions is better choice.

I was thinking of using Crypto AES for this, but after [asking "is it ok?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76730/crypto-aes-for-authentication)" - answer was no, i'm not an expert in crypto, so i didn't fully understood a reason.

Here is my initial idea of implementation:

```
/**
 * @param {string} data dummy
 * @param {string} userKey from database or create new
 * @return {object} {iv, key, encryptedData}
 */
function encrypt(data, userKey) {
  let key = userKey ? Buffer.from(userKey, 'hex') : crypto.randomBytes(32)
  let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16)
  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv)
  let encrypted = cipher.update(data)
  encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()])
  return { iv: iv.toString('hex'), key: key.toString('hex'), encryptedData: encrypted.toString('hex') }
}

/**
 * @param {string} iv
 * @param {string} key
 * @param {string} encryptedData
 * @return {string} decrupted dummy data
 */
function decrypt(iv, key, encryptedData) {
  try {
    iv = Buffer.from(iv, 'hex')
    key = Buffer.from(key, 'hex')
    encryptedData = Buffer.from(encryptedData, 'hex')
    let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv)
    let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedData)
    decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()])
    return decrypted.toString()
  } catch (err) {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but it seems like you want to have a single session for all devices. Usually there is one session per browser per device.

Comment: @Aleuck i have single private key for user and different sessions generated by it for devices.

Answer (score 1):

A way to make it, is that user generate RSA and use [crypto](http://%20chttps://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) with public and private keys, but the public key must always be sent by the user('device')

```
    'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const nodersa = require('node-rsa');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// req.body.value is public key, this never write in database or file
app.post('/', (req, res)=>{
    let value = req.body.value; 
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./store/privateKey.pem', 'utf8');
    const original = new nodersa(privateKey).decrypt(value, 'utf8');
    res.end(original);
});

app.listen(8000, ()=>{
    console.log('on 8000');
});
```

if you use a [public certificate authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) with node, use aditional file called "certification file", node example [here](https://medium.com/nodejs-tips/ssl-certificate-explained-fc86f8aa43d4), this file is issue by C.A. you could work as C.A. and generarte this file, but It is recommended for closed systems, if you not need a gubernamental allow

Comment: where would the user store the private key?

Comment: on your server but he should generate it with some tool other than you or your service, and it should have expiration

Comment: additionally you can use an authorization entity, so that it keeps the private key, only this entity will say if its public key is valid

Comment: sorry, I have modified my answer, hope help you

Comment: what is public key? How to generate it? It's unique for different users? Can i invalidate this key on user logout so that all devices will logout too? How to use it on localhost?

Comment: You can generate it with tools desktop as 'openssl' or online, and if you need invalidate this, only you need generate new rsa pair in your own server, and send public key to email if is necesary, this link generate rsa pair online https://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/

Comment: @Soleil after some reading, i don't think that RSA is a way to go for user authentication. I see no examples in web of using it in that way and i already have https.

Comment: in this days, many people use OAuth 2.0, and other variations like it, and they use a third party to request token, this method only requires that you have a component that has logged in, expiration time token, and secret key, It is not a guarantee to be hacked, because it only requires appropriating the device. in another way, rsa plublic key It is only a file known and located by the user, maybe you not need many security